# TXT entries from gmail overrides my gitlab pages TXT

Tags: dns, gitlab

I'm trying to verify a Gitlab pages domain

So, in my DNS provider, I add a `TXT` register like:

```
_gitlab-pages-verification-code.mysite.example TXT gitlab-pages-verification-code=08206beaab9ad1079993f245f1419a22
```

but I already have

```
@ 3600 IN TXT "v=spf1 mx include:_spf.google.com ?all"
```

that seems to override all my TXT entries.

When I do

```
 dig +short txt mysite.example
```

I will not see the TXT entry as long as I don't delete the google entry.

How should I do that? I also read that I can't delete Google entry because it will periodically check it.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I added

instructions changed, and now letsencrypt ask me that:

```
Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.mysite.io with the following value:

gcnw0KaBOs8lMALx9YvIYsq8ZCWyxCLieMfqxxxxx

Before continuing, verify the record is deployed.
```

so, I removed @ TXT even if not necessary... and added the TXT entry:

```
@ 10800 IN A 35.185.44.232
imap 10800 IN CNAME access.mail.gandi.net.
pop 10800 IN CNAME access.mail.gandi.net.
smtp 10800 IN CNAME relay.mail.gandi.net.
webmail 10800 IN CNAME webmail.gandi.net.
www 10800 IN CNAME mysite.io.
@ 10800 IN MX 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
_acme-challenge.mysite.io 300 IN TXT "gcnw0KaBOs8lMALx9YvIYsq8ZCWyxCLieMxxxxxxx"
```

I waited a whole night, and when I execute:

```
dig +short txt _acme-challenge.mysite.io
```

It doesn't give me anything.

PD: Sorry about not being a programming question, what is the place where I should  post ?

Comment: What if you do `dig +short txt _gitlab-pages-verification-code.mysite.fr`?

Comment: the only way I could make gitlab verify domain is with @, so in this case, the command below will return nothing

Comment: You can have multiple TXT records per record. In your case it is not even the same records (`@` vs `_gitlab-pages-verification-code`). The TXT for `@` does not override anything, it is just the entry returned when querying for the domain name (which `@` is an alias of in zonefiles) itself. You are not specifying the provider used nor in fact your domain so it is pretty difficult for anyone to help you, besides the fact that this is not very programming related...

Comment: The SOA record of `mysite.io` reveals `2018110100` as serial which strongly suggests that the zone was not changed since 2018-11-01. Hence your TXT record is not published. You will need to see with your DNS provider to make sure your TXT record gets published properly.  `dig @$(dig +short NS mysite.io | head -1) TXT _acme-challenge.mysite.io +short` returns nothing and until it does the CA validation will not work.

Comment: sorry patrick, mysite.io was an example, my real site is different. My problem was I had to add `_gitlab-pages-verification-code TXT "gitlab-code"` instead of `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.mysite.io TXT "gitlab-code"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `dig _gitlab-pages-verification-code.mysite.example TXT` and you will see your TXT record for Gitlab verification.

When you do `dig mysite.example TXT` it returns only TXT records on the `mysite.example` record, not all TXT records in your zone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Patrick, I updated my question with new data